# php preg_match_all multimatch to string

Tags: php, preg-match-all

my first Q here and im new to PHP :)

text.txt

```
11085520 11sometext11 22somemoretext22 
21546888 11othertext11 22foundtext22
```

PHP

```
$string = file_get_contents('text.txt');
$pattern = "/11(.*)11/"; // This is no problem 
$pattern2 = "/22(.*)22/"; // This is the problem // i do understand that i not use pattern2 but so you understand the search i try to make :) 

$found = preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $results);
if ($found) {
    // Loop out result from both column to a sting
    var_dump($results);
} else {
    echo ('No match');
}
```

Am i thinking in wrong way? Is it better ways to do it?
At the end i want to loop out file(s) and get it in to MySql 
With hope for help // T

Comment: What are the rules you want to check for? You want to read [SO's how-to on asking good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: What i try to get out is brackets in $pattern and $pattern2 as string so i can loop it out to mysql
first match is on line 11085520

Comment: Well, i don't understand what's about $pattern2, be more explicit.

Comment: ohh sorry :)
from textfile, get results from each line to table row in MySql :)
In this case, match is found in line 11085520 and line 21546888 
(match of both $pattern and $pattern2 is needed. - im sorry for not be so clear - but hard when i dont understand myself =P

Comment: Edit your post and explain what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is what you are looking for:

```
/(\d+)[\s\S]*?11(.*)11[\s\S]*?22(.*)22[\s\S]*?/
```

[Regexr example](http://regexr.com/3cgtg)

**Explanation :**

- `(\d+)`        -  Match 1 or more numeric digits (your primary key i guess)
- `[\s\S]*?`  -  Match any number of any characters BUT match as few as possible (i.e. not eating up the rest of the string).
- `11(.*)11`  -  Match any non-blank characters between 11 and 11.
- `[\s\S]*?`  -  Match any number of any characters BUT match as few as possible (i.e. not eating up the rest of the string).
- `22(.*)22`  -  Match any non-blank characters between 22 and 22.
- `[\s\S]*?`  -  Match any number of any characters BUT match as few as possible (i.e. not eating up the rest of the string).

**Example**

```
11085520 11sometext11 22sdffds22 //matches: [11085520,sometext,sdffds]

11085520 11sos24mesd5text11 222222 //matches: [11085520,sos24mesd5text,22]

11085520 11somet-=/.ext11 22some'./'.moretext22 //matches: [11085520,somet-=/.ext,some'./'.moretext]

11085520 11som'.etext11 22so./'.;[;.
memoretext22                      //newline messes up matching, no match

1108ds5520 11sometext11 22somemoretext22 //matches: [1108,sometext,somemoretext]

11085 520 11sometext11 22somemoretext22 //matches: [11085,sometext,somemoretext]

11085520 11sometext11 22somemoretext22 //matches: [11085520,sometext,somemoretext]
```

Comment: ThisNameBetterBeAvailable - Thanks a lot, new way of use RegEx for me,  just what i needed!!! (im sorry, dont know how to Vote - but when i find out you have it at once 

To everyone - great site!!! 10min and i solve problem!!

Comment: @TyroneFröberg: Just did it for you, simply press the arrows up on the left of the answer.

Comment: @TyroneFröberg Great! Good luck with your project!

Comment: lmao - sometime you dont see the forrest cose of the trees :) Thanks a lot again!!